# How to get child element data using python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

What I'm trying to do is get the data from the child element in the below code:

```
<div class="ListContainer">
    <ul class="uiList">
        ...
    </ul>
<div class="expandedList">
<ul>
    <div id="1012450"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
    <div id="1012451"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
    <div id="1012452"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
    <div id="1012453"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="expandedList">
<ul>
    <div id="1012454"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
    <div id="1012455"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
    <div id="1012456"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
    <div id="1012457"><a href="#"><img /></a></div>
</ul>
</div>
....
....
</div>
```

I want to get the id of each div inside the expandedList class. I tried using xpath but that not capturing all the expandedList.

Comment: show your xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div_ids = []
for div_element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.expandedList div[id]'):
    div_ids.append(div_element.get_attribute('id'))
```